# Insulation in partially finished basement (2yo home)

Tags: insulation, basement, basement-insulation

I am in the process of finishing the basement in my 2-year old home. I live in Wisconsin, and our basement has insulation already - 1” foam board on the exterior of the concrete foundation (I believe R=5) and R=19 fiberglass batt insulation on the ~3-4 feet of studded walls above ground. The existing foundation and finished walls have a vapor barrier already. I am finishing about 1000 sq ft of the 1500 sq foot basement and leaving 500 sq ft unfinished for storage/utility space.

My current plan is to put unfaced fiberglass batt insulation (R=13) behind the drywall on all exterior walls in the finished spaces up to the height of the top of the concrete foundation wall. I’d then add mineral wool insulation in a few interior walls bordering a bedroom and in the ceiling of the finished areas to deaden footsteps. A few questions I would greatly appreciate some advice on…

1. Any first-glance problems with this plan?
2. I can get fiberglass batts with R=11 for $0.20/sq ft, R=13 for $0.50/sf, or R=15 for $1.20/sf. Do you think the higher R value insulations are worth the extra cost given that I already have some insulation on the foundation walls?
3. I don’t plan to add any extra insulation in the unfinished areas. Is this going to negate the benefits of insulating the finished areas? Should I be insulating between the finished/unfinished areas?
4. For sound deadening, is it worth it to go with products specifically designed for sound reduction (Owens Corning Thermafiber Fire and Sound Guard or Rockwool Safe n Sound) rather than just standard mineral wool insulation? Or would fiberglass even do the trick? Any suggestions on what thickness and insulation types others have used for deadening footsteps in basement ceilings? I don’t need soundproof walls — just some deadening.

Thanks for those who took the time to read and help me out! Happy new year!